# how to find input ("hello world") individually in xy.txt

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I'm trying to make a batch file which checks if the user input does exist in xy.txt well thats easy

but now if the user input is "hello world" i want to check each word individually.

i tried that..

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

:start
set /p word=" "

for /F "tokens=* delims= " %%A in ("%word%") do set A=%%A & set B=%%B 


if %A%=="" goto Anovalue
if not %A%=="" goto checkforA

:Anovalue
echo first word has no value
pause

 if %B%=="" goto Bnovalue
 if not %A%=="" goto checkforB

 :Bnovalue
 echo second word has no value
 pause
 goto start

 :checkforA
 findstr /c:"%A%" xy.txt > NUL
 if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto notexistA
 if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto existA

  :checkforB
  findstr /c:"%B%" xy.txt > NUL
  if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto notexistB
  if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto existB

  :existA
  echo first word does exist in xy.txt
  pause
  goto checkforB

  :existB
  echo second word does exist in xy.txt
  pause
  goto start

  :notexistA
  echo first word does not exist in xy.txt
  pause
  (echo %A%) >>xy.txt
  goto checkforB

 :notexistB
 echo second word does not exist in xy.txt
 pause
(echo %B%) >>xy.txt
goto start\
```

Couldn't I do that in a more easier and smarter way?

Comment: I've answered the same question today [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19854251/2861476)

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see it. Thank you very much, but that's not the answer I'm looking for..

Comment: And, what answer are you looking for?

Comment: I want to check every word individually means: first the hello and then world. I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Well, thank you. The code provided does exacty what you are asking for. For each word in your input, tests if it is in file.

Comment: So there is no other way to do that? An easier way?

Comment: Do you want to find out if **both** words are in a text file, on any lines?  Or do you want to find the term `hello world` on one line?

Comment: Yeah in any line, but first i want check the hello and then the world. Every word individually

Comment: Edit your question and show us some text with `hello` and `world` in it, and then add what you want to see in the output.

Comment: My code is in the post and it works but i asked if there's an easier smarter version of this program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do what you are asking to do, many of which use a lot less code.  For instance, given the following file `xy.txt`:

```
this is a test of the
system to see if it
will work the way
that i want it to
work today
```

This batchfile (`check.bat`):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set words=%1
set words=!words:"=!
for %%i in (!words!) do findstr /I /C:"%%i" xy.txt > NUL && echo     Found - %%i || echo Not Found - %%i

endlocal
```

Well return the following:

```
c:\>check "is test smart"
    Found - is
    Found - test
Not Found - smart
```

However, words within a word will also return true.  For instance, `check "day"` will find `day`, even though it is not a separate word because it is part of `today`.  Handling that situation would be a little more tricky.  To do that, you need to encapsulate the search words with some character, and then replace all the spaces in `xy.txt` with the same encapsulation character.  For instance, if we use a `.`, replace all spaces in `xy.txt` whwith the `.`, and then search for `.word.`, we will find only whole words that match.

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set words=%1
set words=!words:"=!
set words=.!words: =. .!.

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (xy.txt) do (
  set line=%%i
  set line=.!line: =.!.
  echo !line!>>xy.txt.tmp
)

for %%i in (!words!) do (
  set word=%%i
  set word=!word:.=!
  findstr /I /C:"%%i" xy.txt.tmp > NUL && echo     Found - !word! || echo Not Found - !word!
)

del xy.txt.tmp

endlocal
```

I chose to create an intermediary file `xy.txt.tmp` to house the edited file where the spaces are replaced with `.`.  Then we can execute the following command and get the displayed results:

```
c:\>check "this is a test of the stem today that will work each day"
    Found - this
    Found - is
    Found - a
    Found - test
    Found - of
    Found - the
Not Found - stem
    Found - today
    Found - that
    Found - will
    Found - work
Not Found - each
Not Found - day
```

It correctly finds words at the beginning of the line, end of the line and anywhere in between.  The only downside is the intermediate file that it creates and then deletes.  Doing it without an intermediate file would be a bit more complex...

Comment: Too bad I didn't click the link provided by @MCND in the first comment of the question before I spent time writing this answer.  Our answers are very similar.  The OP must have reposted the question when they didn't get the answer they were looking for...  It seems no matter how you ask the question, you're going to get a very similar answer.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry, but thank you very much. Can you please make it that the program would say false even the word is in another word? I would be much happier, because that's I'm actually looking for. I really appreciate your answers.

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to exclude partial word matches.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, but it doesn't work for me. I just press enter and nothing happens and i don't know how the program can check words from the xy.txt either, because in the code there's only a !file! and no xy.txt  Can you please help me? I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Will it always be `xy.txt`, or might it be a different filename sometimes?  You'll notice that I included `xy.txt` as one of the parameters when running `check.bat`.  It is parameter `%2`.  So you can pass in `xy.txt` on the command-line, like I did, or I can modify he code so that `xy.txt` is hardcoded.  What is your preference?

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! I'd like to have the xy.txt already in the code. And it is possible to do that without an intermediate file? Would be that a lot of work or is it easy make it?

Comment: Adding `xy.txt` into the code is very easy.  Doing it without an intermediate file is not.  Sorry.  Already invested way too much time into writing this for you.  You should have enough understanding to do it yourself, asking for help in the troublesome spots.  Stake Overflow is not a rent-a-[free]coder.com site, or the like.

Comment: Thank you very much altough! I'll try myself and I'll let you know if I am succesful.